# How to insert multiple value onto one column with different rows?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to store the question text and answer into different table. First I can stored the question text value, but subsequently when I insert the value for answer, it display

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1'

My objective is to store the question text on question table and answer in option table. I have tried a few method, but still can't get it to work. Those commented line are some of my methods.

HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="goBack()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span> Back
  </button><br><br>
  <p></p>
  <form class="table" method="post" id="mcq-form">
    <table class="table">

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Question:</td>
          <td><input type="text" size="80" name="questiontext"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>1. </td>
          <td><input type="text" size="70" name="ans1"><input value="1" name="ans" type="radio"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2. </td>
          <td><input type="text" size="70" name="ans2"><input value="2" name="ans" type="radio"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3. </td>
          <td><input type="text" size="70" name="ans3"><input value="3" name="ans" type="radio"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4. </td>
          <td><input type="text" size="70" name="ans4"><input value="4" name="ans" type="radio"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table></form>
</div>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

require_once 'dbConn.php';

if(!empty($_POST{'submit'})) {

    //$questiontext = $_POST['questiontext'];
    $anstext1 = $_POST['ans1'];
    $anstext2 = $_POST['ans2'];
    $anstext3 = $_POST['ans3'];
    $anstext4 = $_POST['ans4'];
    //$radiobtn = $_POST['ans'];

    //add the first record into question table
    /*$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `question`(question_text) VALUES(:questiontext)");
    $stmt1->bindParam(":questiontext",$questiontext);
    $stmt1->execute();*/

    //$answerArray = array["$anstext1", "$anstext2", "$anstext3", "$anstext4"];
    /*$value = array(':ans1', 'ans2', ':ans3', 'ans4');
    for($i=0; $i<=count($value); $i++) {
        $i = $value[$i];
    }*/

    $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `option_tbl`(option_answer) VALUES(':ans1', ':ans2', 'ans3', 'ans4')");

    $stmt2->bindParam(":ans1",$anstext1);
    $stmt2->bindParam(":ans2",$anstext2);
    $stmt2->bindParam(":ans3",$anstext3);
    $stmt2->bindParam(":ans4",$anstext4);
    $stmt2->execute();
    //$stmt2->execute();

    /*$conn->beginTransaction();

    //insert first query to question table
    $questionsql = ("INSERT INTO `question`(question_text) VALUES(:questiontext)");
    $q = $conn->prepare($questionsql);
    $q->bindValue(":questiontext",$questiontext);
    $q->execute();

    //insert second query to option table
    $answersql = ("INSERT INTO `option_tbl`(option_answer) VALUES(:ans1, :ans2, :ans3,:ans4)") ;
    $a = $conn->prepare($answersql);
    $a->bindValue("anstext1",$anstext1);
    $a->bindValue("anstext2",$anstext2);
    $a->bindValue("anstext3",$anstext3);
    $a->bindValue("anstext4",$anstext4);
    $a->execute();
    $conn->commit();*/

}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all , you do not store multiple values in one column. You store them in multple rows. The error you have comes directly from this

```
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `option_tbl`(option_answer) VALUES(':ans1', ':ans2', 'ans3', 'ans4')");
```

You are telling sql that you want to store something in the `option_answer` column but you are sending 4 different values.

it should look something like this:

```
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `option_tbl`(option_answer) VALUES(:ans)");
```

Then

```
$stmt2->bindParam(":ans",$anstext1);
$stmt2->execute()
...
$stmt2->bindParam(":ans",$anstext4);
$stmt2->execute()
```

This still doesn't get you out of the woods. How do you know which question this answer relates to? YOu probably want something like

```
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `option_tbl`(question, option_answer) VALUES(':question, :ans')");
```

Comment: How can i store the input type of text because using the 'ans' is storing the value of radio button?

Comment: It printed 8 time of this ":ans" in the option_answer column. I wonder what is the mistake here.

Comment: I got any question is that how i insert option_answer based on the question_id that i have inserted for the question_text ?

Comment: The first question is solved by this $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `option_tbl`(option_answer) VALUES(:ans)");

Comment: "how i insert option_answer based on the question_id that i have inserted for the question_text" if you are inserting the question record now you can make use of the [last insert id](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) , if the question is a previously saved record, you will have to fetch it's id

Comment: the question is saved on the first query, and after that it will save the option_answer along with the question_id in the option table.

Comment: you have to save the question first, get the insert id and use it when saving the options

Answer (score 0):

@e4c5 explained it well enough why this is not working....

Try it like (You may also want to store question id else this will be of no use...Assuming you can edit it yourself according to your need...)

```
<?php

require_once 'dbConn.php';

if(!empty($_POST{'submit'})) {

    //$questiontext = $_POST['questiontext'];
    $answers[] = $_POST['ans1'];
    $answers[] = $_POST['ans2'];
     $answers[] = $_POST['ans3'];
     $answers[] = $_POST['ans4'];
    //$radiobtn = $_POST['ans'];

    //add the first record into question table
    /*$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `question`(question_text) VALUES(:questiontext)");
    $stmt1->bindParam(":questiontext",$questiontext);
    $stmt1->execute();*/

    //$answerArray = array["$anstext1", "$anstext2", "$anstext3", "$anstext4"];
    /*$value = array(':ans1', 'ans2', ':ans3', 'ans4');
    for($i=0; $i<=count($value); $i++) {
        $i = $value[$i];
    }*/
foreach( $answers as $answer){
    $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `option_tbl`(option_answer) VALUES(':ans')");

    $stmt2->bindParam(":ans",$answer);
    $stmt2->execute();
    //$stmt2->execute();
}
    /*$conn->beginTransaction();

    //insert first query to question table
    $questionsql = ("INSERT INTO `question`(question_text) VALUES(:questiontext)");
    $q = $conn->prepare($questionsql);
    $q->bindValue(":questiontext",$questiontext);
    $q->execute();

    //insert second query to option table
    $answersql = ("INSERT INTO `option_tbl`(option_answer) VALUES(:ans1, :ans2, :ans3,:ans4)") ;
    $a = $conn->prepare($answersql);
    $a->bindValue("anstext1",$anstext1);
    $a->bindValue("anstext2",$anstext2);
    $a->bindValue("anstext3",$anstext3);
    $a->bindValue("anstext4",$anstext4);
    $a->execute();
    $conn->commit();*/

}
?>
```

Comment: I still can't store the input value text. It resulted 8 rows of ":ans" in the column.